# How to get the record details which has been changed in Access database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i am having an Access database with many tables and thousands of records in it, if anybody changes any data in it , any row, or even only a cell, is there any way to get to know what specific row or cell has been changed in the Access database, any property or should I use any trigger ?

Comment: Triggers came in 2010 I believe. So your only option is manually compare old vs new (beforePost event?). Saying that doing it with Triggers isn't particularly clever either. Doing it for any change anywhere, access or not, will soon rack up a huge amount of data, on a non-trivial system. What problem are you trying to solve, lateral thinking time.

Comment: actually the main thing is if any specific row is edited, instead of uploading the whole database, it would be helpful if i upload that specific changed row or table only , somehow by getting the row edited, can you suggest me any way of doing that

Comment: Basically, all that is required is to keep the track of database, and i want to know if there is any property in Access which can be used to track whenever something is edited

Comment: Some RDBMSs have the concept of a 'ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP', but I don't know if access supports this natively.  You could do something at the application level, maybe, to get the effect - then, merely upload everything since the last update.  However, there could be issues with transactions, if something goes wrong - you may need to look into an ETL tool.

Comment: Thnx !!! i will look out for it. Please do suggest me if u get any other way

Comment: I have long found it useful to add a timestamp field (column) to every editable table. There are some notes [here](http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=12731) on checking differences.

Comment: I just add a DateTimeModified field and I make sure I always update that field from any form or other code that makes record changes. Yeah, I know triggers are preferred if they are available.

Comment: no there are no triggers.. I checked this timestamp thing, but the problem is now i'll have to keep another table which will have the time and date to compare with and i'll have to check the last date before this current modifiaction, how will i compare that which one is last updation date

Comment: I just checked time stamp but it wont be useful because, when i'll insert new data it will work fine, but hen any existing data will be updated , the time wont chnage

Comment: This comes down to where you going to place thijs update code. As noted, in Access 2010, you do have table triggers, and thus it would be a simple matter to place some code in the tables before change event. This event could set the value a create date/time column and also update a LastMod column. So this would occur automatic and independent of any code or forms or sql update query run in this data. However as noted this ability and feature is only available in Access 2010.

Comment: You just need DateTimeModified fields in both of your data stores. It's a simple thing to compare them then. Just make sure you have code to always update this field. It works the best to use the Form's BeforeUpdate Event. Just put something like this in there: Me!DateTimeModified = Now()

Comment: Actually I have no idea where to put the conditions in Access, should I create a macro, but I dont know how would I cal that macro

Comment: is there any way if timestamp property can be updated when data is updated, because timestamp inserts the current dat only in the new inserted row, i am trying to find out if it can updat the time in existing rows too...

Comment: @DeppG If you are using Access, why have you tagged MySQL as well?  Anyway, if it is just Access then your best option is to look at creating a replicated database (in-built feature) and then synchronising these at certain times.

Comment: I would not suggest replica databases. I remember them with some pain.

Comment: Yes, the timestamp property can be updated when the record is changed. You can use the before change table event to run code at the engine level (you need a2010 to do this).  In fact, if the application is not going to be updated by anything else then Access, then you could even log the current windows logged on user name and also that of the computer workstation name. So you can log network user name, computer name, and the date/time. If you don't have 2010, the you have to place such code in the forms before update event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem a couple of years back with an MSSQL DB and I seem to recall that both ACCESS (MDB) and SQL (MDF) Databases DON't inherantly support this. You, if I am not mistaken, will have to adopt the principles:

1) Transactional Data should NEVER be adited, only reference historical records with new records containing the changed values. I took it from three angles :

- I had a column called PrecursorRecId which held the record_id of the
  most recent record  the update related to.
- Another column held and Context_ID under which all related records
  were linked by a common value which was the key Id column of
  AuditTxnContext table.
- Record's TxnDate (pretty logical)

2) Master Data records Also were not altered but each record had an EffectiveFromDate and and EffectiveToDate where the records with a NULL EffectiveToDate were considered current. Depending on the sensiitivity of the table, creation of MaterData records was accompanied by Audit Entry records. Again, there is a RecordCreatedDateTime which does not automatically match the EffectiveFromDate stamp.

This may help you going forward but there's not much to assist with your existing data. I also don't have much idea of what it is you are working on so my input is fairly generic. I hope it helps any way. I would welcome anyone's input if I am in error, this is just how we approached our challenge.

Tell me a bit more if you are still dealing with it. If not, maybe close your question.

Cheers

Mac