# Access 2007 Timestamp

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there any property in Access that can be used such that whenever any cell in Access database is edited, it is used to update the corresponding cell of any other column.

Actually if i am thinking of using timestamp, it works only for insert , not for update and when i edit any cell I want it keep the track that what has been edited. I cannot use forms in Access, and access 2007 does not support stored procedure or triggers .

Comment: Any possibility of upgrading to Access 2012, which has something very like triggers called data macros?

Comment: Is there something wrong with continuing your earlier question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193096/how-to-get-the-record-details-which-has-been-changed-in-access-database) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am thinking of using timestamp, it works only for insert , not for
>   update... access 2007 does not support stored procedure or triggers

Actually, Access 2007 supports [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/create-procedure-statement-HA001231440.aspx) but does not support procedural code as such; an Access `PROCEDURE` consists of a single Access SQL statement.

You could do something along these lines:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateMyStuff
(
 arg_stuff_ID CHAR(10), 
 arg_stuff_name VARCHAR(20) = NULL, 
 arg_stuff_color_code INTEGER = NULL
)
UPDATE MyStuff
   SET stuff_name 
          = IIF( arg_stuff_name IS NULL, stuff_name, arg_stuff_name ),
       stuff_color_code 
          = IIF( arg_stuff_color_code IS NULL, stuff_color_code, arg_stuff_color_code ),   
       stuff_updated_date = NOW()
 WHERE stuff_ID = arg_stuff_ID;
```

You could write similar procedures for `INSERT` and `DELETE` then revoke update permission from the tables, thereby forcing users to update the data via your procedures which of course ensure the timestamp is maintained.

IIRC the value of the current timestamp `NOW()` will be taken from the users's local machine, even if the database file resides on a server machine, but that's just one of the 'joys' of Access.

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing built-in. Use linked tables to an external table from a database engine that supports triggers.

Otherwise you can implement this with Forms using VBA.

Comment: does Access creates any log when we edit the database, however i dont think so , because it doesnot support any save point too

Comment: No, I've never seen any log output from a Microsoft Jet Database Engine

Comment: In a2010, with the new table triggers, there is a command called logevent that writes out your expression in code to the log table. However, as noted, since you do have triggers, then I would likely create a column or even another table and write out to that, as that log file will grow rather fast and then you have to have someone empty it.